# Packet loss on a single Windows 10 machine in the network

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, packet, packet-loss

I am having this issue where one of my computers keeps freezing the transferences between any of the nodes of the network.

It runs on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19044.

[Packet Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jXxI.png)

[Intermittent Freezing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbrMB.png)

First time I saw it was uploading a 45 GB folder to my NAS, comprised of small size (~1 MB) files. It uploaded at peak speed for around 30 seconds and then dropping the speed to zero. Then restarting the transfer and the cycle repeats.

This behavior also happens while browsing internet.

I have tried 2 different WiFI USB adapters and 1 Ethernet integrated port, so wireless and wired. Same behavior.

I also tried:

- Flushing DNS.
- Resetting winsock.
- Resetting ipv4 and ipv6 config.
- Disabling Microsoft WiFi Direct Virtual Adapter.
- Pinging the router, the NAS, the DNS and other WAN servers.
- Pinging 127.0.0.1 to check the TCP stack. Everything fine is here.
- Disabling Windows Firewall.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try running DISM/SFC  ...   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete   ..  Then run TCP/IP reset again, restart and test.     ,,,,, Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: As far as I know packets through 127.0.0.1 never goes through the network stack on Windows, instead they take a short-cut. So I don't think that you can check the TCP stack by pinging 127.0.0.1. Better ping the public IP of the used network adapter.